# Get values selected from SelectBox Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angularjs and I have selectBox with two variables (startDate and endDate):

```
    <div>
      <select class="form-control" ng-model="date.time">
        <option ng-repeat="time in dateList" value="{{time.startDate}},{{time.endDate}}" >
         {{time.startDate| date:'medium'}} - {{time.endDate | date:'medium'}}</option>
     </select>
    </div>
```

After the user select a period I want to get the startDate and endDate  separately.

Comment: first, don't use `ng-repeat` in select options, use `ng-options` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking at what your value holds when you're done selecting? You'll get the string you put inside the option's `value`.

```
var dates = $scope.date.time.split(','),
    startDate = dates[0],
    endDate = dates[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

With the ng-options syntax you can set to your date.time the whole object:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="date.time" ng-options="time as ((time.startDate | date:'medium') + ' - ' + (time.endDate | date:'medium')) for time in dateList"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

What ever you have bound in your ng-model will hold the selected value.

In your case the ng-model is holding date.time, which may not be what you are looking for.

Additionally you should set the value to be the data that you wish to extract from the option list.

Please see this (poorly and quickly constructed) [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/8628/)

html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <select class="form-control" ng-model="selected">
       <option ng-repeat="time in dateList" value="{{time}}" >
        {{time.prop}}</option>
    </select>
    {{selected}}
</div>
```

js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selected = 'plz select a thing';
    $scope.dateList = [{prop:'prop1'}, {prop:'prop2'}];
}
```